In Python is there a way to calculate a row from the previous row calculation?
I have a table like below and am looking to calculate the "Rollover" (Previous D value + B - C).
I am currently using: df['Rollover'] = (df['Rollover'].shift(1) + df['B'] - df['C']) but after the second row, the value does not take the previous 'Rollover' value.


IIUC, sum columns B and C, then use cumsum:
df["Rollover"] = df["B"].add(df["C"]).cumsum()

           A  B  C  D  E  Rollover
0 2024-01-01  1  1  1  1         2
1 2024-01-02  2  1  1  1         5
2 2024-01-03  2  2  2  2         9
3 2024-01-04  1  1  1  1        11
4 2024-01-05  4  4  4  4        19
5 2024-01-06  1  1  1  1        21
6 2024-01-07  4  4  4  4        29
7 2024-01-08  2  1  1  1        32
8 2024-01-09  4  4  4  4        40

